# Can I create a directory that occupies more than 1 data block? ext3

Tags: filesystem, directory, ext3

I wanted to ask if it is possible that a directory can occupy more than 1 datablock, in my case, I use 4096 as size for the blocks.

In case it is possible, how could I do it?

I have a small file system created in my ubuntu for the university of 512M and they ask me to create a directory that occupies more than 1 datablockm but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: If you add files inside your directory, it will be bigger. Try `touch empty-{1..1000}`

Comment: Do your directory blocks need to be contiguous? (Probably less important on non-spinning media).